# Importing ODBC database to MS SQL 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, odbc

How do I get a database from ODBC data source to SQL Server 2005? Can I use SQL Managment Studio Express for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Right-click on your database and go to Tasks: Import Data.

Answer (score 0):

It used to be called DTS, but every SQL Server 2005/2008 comes with something called SSIS that is used to import and export data.   You can import data into a database from any source, including flat text file, or .xls spreadsheet.